# how to make noUiSlider work

Tags: javascript, slider

I need a 2-handle slider which displays the handle value when I move it.  I am using nouislider.  I am having problem making it work.  I stripped off unwanted most code and will add the move and change good stuff later.  How do I initialize the slider? Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery No UI Slider - Range slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nouislider.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.8b1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.nouislider.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="example">
      <div id="noUiSlider" class="noUiSlider"></div>
      <div id="valueInput">
        START <input type="text" id="start" value="0"/></label>
        END   <input type="text" id="end" value="60"/></label>
      </div>

      <script>
        window.onload =$(function(){                        
          $("#noUiSlider").empty().noUiSlider( 'init', {
            handles: 2,
            connect: true,
            scale:[10,30],
            start:[0,60]
          });
        </script>           
      </div>
   </body>    
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {                        
   $("#noUiSlider").noUiSlider({
       handles: 2,
       connect: true,
       scale:[10,30],
       start:[0,60]
   });
});
```